# How to start mobile app from wear app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an Android wear app that send messages from and to a companion mobile app.
When the mobile app is active all runs fine, if the companion mobile app is not active i need to be Able to launch it from wear app... How do i launch the mobile app from the wear app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement a WearableListenerService in your mobile app and send a Message from wear app.
Here a little gist to achieve it.

//Mobile app

```
public class ListenerServiceFromWear extends WearableListenerService {

    private static final String HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        /*
         * Receive the message from wear
         */
        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH)) {

            //For example you can start an Activity
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }

    }     
}
```

You have to declare it in your Manifest.

```
  <service android:name=".ListenerServiceFromWear">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Can you add wear part to send Message? Would be great as I can't get it to work.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i install app on wearable, and launch it doesnot effect.
Then i manually install mobile.app on mobile device, and launch on wearable device it does not effect too.
What i do wrong?

Comment: The com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER action is deprecated

Comment: either deprecated here or doesnt work